# How can i get any running activity context in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, get, external, android-context

I'm want to start external activity and get his context,
so I can extract his (the new activity) views and other object that requires the context object.

Again, the external activity doesn't related to my activity (or my java code),
it can be any app.

How can I achieve that context?

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. You cannot get an `Activity` or a `Context` from a foreign process.